# Does a function based view in Django returning JSON response considered RESTful?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

A function based view in Django which authenticates the user based on the sessionid and requests using X-CSRFToken(for POST calls) which returns data in JSON is considered RESTFul? I am currently not using djangorestframework for my project.

Comment: REST doesn't actually exist. It generally just means not using any other API framework

Comment: What I am trying to find is that if we follow the principles of REST and build that in Django's function-based view, without actually using the out-of-the-box djangorestframework package, then does that still qualify as RESTful, or does this package does something more?

Comment: RESTful isn't a thing. Any API is technically restful since it's a meaningless concept